# Need to push object into firebase array with val()

Tags: javascript, firebase

I've recently gotten started with Firebase development in React.js -

At the moment, I'm trying to pull from the database and create a new object with the data.

This is the code:

```
var arr = firebase.database().ref("news");//this is the ref.

arr.once('value', function (snapshot) {//will return the array value
    model = {//this is the model i want to .push()
        title: title,
        content: content,
        img: img,
        category: category,
        likes: likes,
        id: snapshot.val().length//This is where I want to add the arr.length
    };

    var promise = arr.push(model);

    promise.then(function(){
        ...
    })
})
```

The problem is that arr.push(model) runs BEFORE the `model.id` variable is loaded.

Comment: Does the `snapshot` argument has a `val()` function?

Comment: `snapshot.val()` get you a javascript object. do you want to get how many children in it?

Comment: @Luis I’ve tried that but it wont work either! Maybe calling an ‘on’ function when the array.val() is called? Don’t know how to implement it..

Comment: The array.push is called before the snapshot.val()... .val() is asymchronous :(

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: @Hareesh Sorry about the poor details, I've updated it now

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is snapshot.val() returns a object and not a array. Hence, it would return undefined if u try to access snapshot.val().length.

Now the solution is to convert object to array to get the count.

```
id: Object.keys(snapshot.val()).length
```

This might solve your problem.

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @Hareesh, that would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Meghashyam solution should work. Firebase also have a utility `snapshot.numChildren();` which will return `number` of child properties of this `DataSnapshot`, if object is empty it will return `0`

```
model = {
    title: title,
    content: content,
    img: img,
    category: category,
    likes: likes,
    id: snapshot.numChildren()
};
```

You can check more details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numChildren)